# Macro to copy to value in a defined cell and paste that value the the bottom of a list

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to build a macro that will only copy the return value from a vlookup function of a specific cell (B2) and paste it the first empty cell of a column (Column H on the same worksheet beginning at cell H2).

Comment: Sounds like you don't need a macro for this. Have you tried using `VLOOKUP` first? What problems did you have with it if you did?

Comment: lastColumn = Range("XX").End(xlToLeft).Column
Cells(2,lastColumn) = Range("B2")

Comment: Well what I want to do is keep a record of values that the vlookup brings up. So if the lookup bring up value 1XXXX, I want be able to press a button that will copy that  value and paste in in a list in column H, then when another value comes up (saw 2XXXX) in the vlookup, I want to press that same button and have that paste under the value 1XXXX.

Comment: I would probably take a look at a [`Worksheet_Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb210472%28v=office.12%29.aspx) event. You should be able to find some examples of how it's used on stackoverflow. You can update your question with any code you've tried that isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Assign this macro to your button:

```
Sub CopyVLookup()
    Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = [B2]
End Sub
```

This finds the last cell in `H` column with a value and moves to the cell below it and sets its value equal to the current value of `B2`

Answer (score 0):

If the formula to be captured is in cell B2, then try this tiny macro:

```
Sub surface()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If n < 2 Then n = 2
    Range("H" & n).Value = Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: just a quick note, if Column H is blank then the end up will return row 1, if you add 1 to row one the absolute minimum value it could be is 2, so there is no need to test if less then 2, you would have to return Row 0 in the end method to get 0+1 < 2, and there is no row 0 in excel =)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, didn't test it though:

```
dim lookingFor as String
dim fromVlookup as String
dim whereToSave as Long

lookingFor = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1).Cells("2", "B").Value
fromVLookup = = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookingFor, "A1:B2", 2, 0)
whereToSave = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1).Cells(whereToSave, "H").Value = fromVlookup
```